# ASCII entities causing errors when parsing XML in R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to parse a web page using the xml package in R.  The XML has some special characters inside attribute names, example: `<B name="A &lt; 0">`, which getNodeSet() doesn't like.  I thought the whole point of using `&lt;` was to avoid problems with < being reserved.

Here is a reproducible example that throws the error.

```
x <- '
<A>
<B name="1">
<C name="A &lt; 0"> Value </C>
</B>
</A>
'

getNodeSet(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(x)),"/A/B/C")
```

How can I make this parse cleanly using getNodeSet?

I have a quick workaround, where I used gsub on the raw text to find and replace instances of `&lt;`, but I'm worried about replacing something i didn't intend to replace.  The file also has instances of `&quot;` in the attribute names too.  Same problem.

Is there a more elegant and more general solution than gsub?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for example :

```
   xpathSApply(xmlParse(x),"/A/B/C",xmlGetAttr,'name')
   [1] "A < 0"
```

`xpathSApply` is the equivalent of `sapply`. Note also the use of `xmlParse` and not `xmlTreeParse`.

Comment: Awesome.  That worked.  I needed both attributes and values, so I ended up with this:    `ldply(xpathApply(xmlParse(x), "/A/B/C", function(x) c(name=xmlGetAttr(x, 'name'), value=xmlValue(x))))`

Comment: @NicholasNagle No need to use `ldply`. This works fine : `xpathSApply(xmlParse(x), "/A/B/C", function(x) c(name=xmlGetAttr(x, 'name'),value=xmlValue(x)))` to get attr and value.

Comment: I didn't know that sapply would return a matrix.  Using either one goes through through the 8MB page I was parsing in seconds.  Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasNagle You are welcome. I edit my answer to add a little explanation.

Comment: OK, so now, going back to my original example, I see that getNodeSet works if I use xmlParse instead of xmlTreeParse: `getNodeSet(xmlParse(x),"/A/B/C")`   I'm still trying to figure out this difference...

Comment: @NicholasNagle Note that `xmlTreeParse(useInternalNodes = TRUE,..)`  is equivalent to  `xmlParse(...)`